# Minecraft 1.15.1 scoreboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to track how many times a player breaks a block in a scoreboard. I know you can add every block individually but that would take a while and I thought you could track how many times a certain pic breaks something but then I think everyone in the server need to have the same pic.

Comment: No, I don't think there's an easier way. I'll create a datapack that does this for you, how should the scoreboard be called?

Comment: If you don't even answer that, I'll assume that you're no longer interested in this question, so I won't make the pack.

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'dummy' main objective. Track all picks as seperate objectives, then every second, reset the main objective to 0 and add the score of each pick objective.